# php - How to access objects using string?

Tags: php, oop, object

I know accessing object's properties dynamically using string e.g.

```
$obj->{$string};
```

But what about objects themselves?

Like I have string

```
$obj = '$model->property';
```

How to use this?

For example in if statement, to have something like

`if($model->property)` but by using this string?

Tried `if({$obj})`, `if(${$obj})`... nothing works.

I don't know if it even possible, but maybe?

Comment: You could use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) I guess but it's unsafe...

Comment: @ka_lin tried eval, doesn't work, with eval I've got "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file"

Comment: @ka_lin okay, my bad. added ";" now no exception. But `{{ dd(eval('$model->id;')) }}` gives me null hmmm. Idk, gives me only null all time

Comment: @ka_lin strange, but `{{ dd($model->id) }}` returns me 77 and `{{ dd(eval('$model->id;')) }}` null

Comment: Don't do this. What you are attempting is a bad practice, which will only lead to pain and misery. Besides, you are braking object's encapsulation

Comment: @tereško but there will never be user input associated with it, still bad ?

Comment: @krystian2160 why would existence of "user input" in any way impact if something is or is not a bad programming practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up a small test case...

```
class A {
    public $b = 5;
}

$test = new A();
$var = "test";
echo ${$var}->b;
```

I think this last line is what your after.

**Update:**

If you want the object and the property, then the nearest I could get is to use...

```
class A {
    public $b = 5;
}

$test = new A();
$var = "test->b";
list($var, $property) = explode("->", $var);
echo ${$var}->$property;
```

Comment: But I need object + property in one string, as string and as one

Comment: Can't it be done easier like e.g. `${$var};` ? where `$var = "test->b";` (without usting list and explode)

Comment: Not as far as I know - maybe someone else can come up with a way of doing it.  BUT I would avoid using `eval()`.

Comment: @krystian2160 This is the easiest way. You could also loop trough what the array `explode` returns if you want a variable amount of properties.

Comment: Do you know the reason why it can't be done easier? and simpler and shorter way?

Comment: I think this way IS the simple and short way. It's probably the only way. @krystian2160 . This is the correct answer

Comment: @Joas I know Joas, thank you :D. I just wonder why there is no other (easier, simpler) way

Comment: Only guessing - but using $$var is expecting to resolve to a particular variable, with `test->b`, this is a property of a variable.

Comment: @Joas can you tell why `{{ dd(eval('$model->id;')) }}` returns me null (doesn't work properly), while `{{ dd($model->id) }}` returns 77 and works properly?

Comment: Or maybe @NigelRen you know :)?

Comment: Try `dd(eval('return $model->id;'))`, just referencing a variable doesn't mean it passes it's value back.